# Dropdown menu built on html list

Tags: html, css, sass

I've used some html/scss to build a dropdown/select menu (I need to have full control of how the dropdown menu looks like).
The problem is that:

- IE 11 opens the dropdown only when I click the down arrow instead the
  whole text
- in Safari 10.1.1 the dropdown doesn't hide after
  clicking the menu "button" entry

Any help would be quite welcome (answering why it behaves like that would be awesome)

```css
.onclick-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 1em 0px;
  outline-width: 0px;
}

.onclick-menu:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.onclick-menu::before {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

.onclick-menu__date-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 5px 10px 0px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d2d6d9;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 160px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.onclick-menu__date-box::after {
  content: "";
  transform: none;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxzdmcgaGVpZ2h0PSI0OCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDQ4IDQ4IiB3aWR0aD0iNDgiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTE0LjgzIDE2LjQybDkuMTcgOS4xNyA5LjE3LTkuMTcgMi44MyAyLjgzLTEyIDEyLTEyLTEyeiIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wLS43NWg0OHY0OGgtNDh6IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIi8+PC9zdmc+");
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: -90%;
  bottom: 33%;
  z-index: 100;
  min-width: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  max-width: 15px;
  min-height: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  max-height: 11px;
}

.onclick-menu__label {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.onclick-menu-header {
  color: #073590;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.onclick-menu:focus .onclick-menu-content {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  border: 1px solid #e5e7e8;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 8px 8px 6px 0px;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.onclick-menu-content {
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: -1px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-property: visibility;
  background-color: black;
  width: auto;
  border: 5px solid 1px black;
  margin-top: 19px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
}

.onclick-menu-content::after {
  top: -9px;
  border: 10px solid white;
}

.onclick-menu-content::before {
  top: -10px;
  border-bottom-width: 10px solid #e5e7e8;
}

.onclick-menu__date-selector {
  border-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-height: 16px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: #073590;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline-style: none;
}

.onclick-menu-content li {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  outline-width: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 8px;
}

.onclick-menu-content li:hover {
  background-color: #e8f4fd;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: white;
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

button,
html input[type="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.onclick-menu-content button {
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline-width: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="onclick-menu__date-box onclick-menu">
  <label for="date-select" class="onclick-menu__label">
    Take your pick
  </label>
  <span class="onclick-menu-header">
    foo1
  </span>
  <ul id="date-select" class="onclick-menu-content onclick-menu__date-selector">
    <li value="foo1">
      <button value="foo1">
        foo1
      </button>
    </li>
    <li value="foo2">
      <button value="foo2">
        foo2
      </button>
    </li>
    <li value="foo3">
      <button value="foo3">
        foo3
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like a few values/properties that you're working with here aren't compatible with those browsers.  Things like using display:flex; or "width:-webkit-fill-available;" don't work with or have partial support for Safari and IE11  .  Check out www.caniuse.com .

Comment: `:focus` is a really, really bad choice for this - it makes keyboard navigation impossible. If anything, you should use the `:focus-within` pseudo class for this - but browser support for that is still poor, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within I would really recommend that you add a little JS here to achieve the desired functionality, rather than trying to do this using HTML & CSS only.

Comment: @trav I'm open to all suggestions. Can you show me a proof of concept on how you would fix those 2 errors I'm having?

Comment: @CBroe I can also consider using JS, I'm already using it to update the selected value. Can you show an example solution?

Comment: @user2091046  I would suggest a simple google search on how to create a dropdown menu with javascript.   This is one I've referred to before:  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp